# install haskell-platform, get error

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I tried to install haskell-platform with

> brew cask install haskell-platform

But got the following error. How do you fix it?

```
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://haskell.org/platform/download/8.2.1/Haskell%20Platform%2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask haskell-platform
==> Note: running "brew update" may fix sha256 checksum errors
Error: Checksum for Cask 'haskell-platform' does not match.

Expected: b0182bb721b5dff3d66794cbdcea93cec562dc254fcf23c0e7a1a7a8d680aaa7
Actual:   05fc22d2cefdf67f1da2f62a90fda73a746accd08b44ec197046972b82afee06
File:     /Users/william/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/haskell-platform--8.2.1.pkg
```

Comment: have you tried running `brew update`?

Comment: I would recommend you to get started with stack: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Answer (score 0):

A new binary release of HP 8.2.1 was made recently, and announced on the haskell-cafe list: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-October/127979.html

This changed the hash. As noted in the error message, a "brew update" should update the platform cask and pull in the new hash, which should allow things to continue properly.